# Letter 'Z' pronounced as 'Izzard' : how widespread and where?

Tags: pronunciation, alphabet, scottish-english

I read at [Which is the correct way to refer to the letter "Z" — "Zee" or "Zed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6470/which-is-the-correct-way-to-refer-to-the-letter-z-zee-or-zed) 
that the letter Z is pronounced :

> 'Izzard' (/ˈɪzərd/) in Scottish English.

as opposed to *zed* or *zee*.

**Question: Is this really the case in the modern day or is it archaic? Do people really use this in Scotland or elsewhere?**

I ask as I've never heard anyone use  *Izzard* in my life (and I live not a million miles from Scotland). Regarding the history, the [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/izzard#wC8HKMFytol1KhjD.99) says:

> Word History: The curious and charming word *izzard*, meaning “the letter z,” is practically limited to certain fixed expressions in American vernacular English, such as *from A to izzard*, “from beginning to end,” and not *to know A from izzard*, “not to know even the most basic things.”
>
> The English lexicographer Samuel Johnson mentions the word *izzard* as part of his attempt to explain the sound of the letter *z* in the grammar of English he placed at the beginning of his *Dictionary of the English Language*, published in 1755: *Z begins no word originally English; it has the sound, as its name izzard ... expresses, of an s uttered with a closer compression of the palate.*
>
> In Johnson's time, a variant name for the letter z, uzzard, was also in use. Izzard and uzzard are related to zed, the usual name of the letter z in British English. In Scottish English, *z* was also once known as *ezed*, and this form gives us a clue to a possible origin of *izzard*.
>
> // snip

Comment: I lived in scotland (Glasgow) for 7 years, and while i did not tour the country asking people to "pronounce the letter after y please", i've never heard anyone say "izzard", outside the context of the comedian Eddie Izzard (who is not scottish btw).  They would always say "zed", like other british people.

Comment: I've lived in Scotland for 30 years and I've never heard anyone say that either.

Comment: Years ago I wrote [a "text-to-speech" plugin](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,85308.0.html) for the Foobar music player. The first enhancement I had to add was a way of flagging how *British* "OS system voices" should pronounce band names like **ZZ Top** (which by default was spoken as **Zed zed top** in the first version! :)

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I assure you that I have never heard the word "izzard", and that, at least in the regions where I have lived, one might hear "A to Zee", but never "A to izzard".  I am unfamiliar with any form of the expression "not to know A from izzard", though I know several similar expressions that are not based on the alphabet.

Comment: There's a memorable bit from Sesame Street where  the letter Z is called "izzard" while spelling "buzzard", in "rural" American English.

Comment: @Spencer I’d enjoy seeing a video clip with that Sesame Street usage but I expect that’s hard to find ! And in light of your comment, I googled *izzard* with *sesame st*, and found this interesting discussion from 2008 - https://www.bookcrossing.com/forum/5/365301/5667733?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OED: (I, British (England) English speaker, agree with the remark "archaic or dialect.")

> **izzard,** n.
>
> **Pronunciation**: /ˈɪzəd/
>
> **Forms**:  Also 1500s ezod, 1600s yzard, (aphetic zard), 1600s– now dialect uzzard, 1800s izzet; izzart.
>
> **Etymology**: apparently in origin the same word as zed: compare the dialect izzet, uzzit, and the form ĕˈzed, now or formerly in Scotland for zed; also Languedoc izeto, the letter z
>
> *archaic or dialect.*

> **Old name for the letter Z.**

First recorded:

> 1597   T. Morley Plaine & Easie Introd. Musicke 36   *X with y. ezod. & per se.*

Latest record:

> 1837   J. Moultrie Poems 305   *In those days not a soul knew A from Izzard.*

Answer (score 2):

It is very common to pronounce Z as izzard in Hong Kong.

Comment: Hi Matt, and welcome to EL&U. Do you live in HK?

Answer (score 1):

I am from India and here is my two pennies worth on the topic. It is a very commonly occurring mistake here in India to mispronounce zee/zed as (i)zehd which I feel is kinda close to izzard. Now I am not too sure if the two are connected. But there sure is a similarity in the pronunciation.

Answer (score -2):

From my (limited) experience, British English uses "zed" and American English uses "zee". Izzard is a term I've seen used occasionally but it seems to be relatively outdated.

Comment: This just seems to repeat the information from the question.