# How did the name pronunciation of the letter Z as 'zee' become the consensus in American English?

Tags: etymology, history, historical-change

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z#Name_and_pronunciation) as well as my own experiences interacting with people of different nationalities, the pronunciation of 'Z' seems to have maintained some variation of the hard t- sound from the original Greek/Latin "zeta" in most Latin and Germanic languages. The only exceptions I can find are Portugese and American English. In the US, the "zee" pronunciation is so much the unanimous choice, I only recently became aware of this particularly slight against Her Majesty's alphabet.

According to Wikipedia, the 'zee' pronunciation comes "from a late 17th-century English dialectal form," citing a book by Thomas Lye from that period. So, is it fair to assume that this style was popular in England at the time and that American colonists, wanting to keep in vogue with the latest fashions out of the old country took it up?

[The Canadian Encyclopedia](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/zed) offers the opposite explanation--that it was popularized in the spirit of the American Revolution to inspire rebellion against tyrannical taxation and spelling mandates. Another possibility is that it comes from the Alphabet Song, itself an American variation on a long-standing European tradition. (Zee rhymes with me but zed only rhymes with...Ted?) I think this was around the same time we invented football.

Personally, I think the ABC song was probably the most important contributor since it helped so many children learn to read and literacy was considered a valuable skill at that time. Would be interested to hear what others think. Any other possibilities that should be explored?

Comment: What does "so ubiquitous" mean? Either something is everywhere or it is not. You can't have some things being more everywhere than other things. Omnipresence admits no exceptions.

Comment: Zoom, zebra, zero, zone ...

Comment: Can you give IPA examples of the sounds you mean. Italian, for example, has two different sounds for an initial *Z*.

Comment: What does "so unanimous" mean? Either something is of one mind or it is not. You can't have some things being of more than one mind than another. Unity is unique.

Comment: What does "the hard consonant sound" mean? What would it mean **not** to have "the hard consonant sound"? What does a hard consonant sound like?

Comment: What Americans were **already in America *before* the 17th century** that they would have needed to keep up with the old country when the 17th century rolled along? I'm pretty sure they were speaking Spanish not English before the 17th century in Saint Augustine, so you seem to have the wrong old country here. The English didn't arrive until the 17th century. Only the Spanish arrived in the 16th.

Comment: Where might I read about these “tyrannical spelling mandates” from the then-King of Great Britain that the American Founding Fathers rose up in violent revolution against? Have you spell-checked the Declaration of Independence lately? *He has **endeavoured** to prevent the population of these States..For transporting us beyond Seas to be tried for pretended **offences**..For abolishing the free System of English Laws in a **neighbouring** Province..and has **endeavoured** to bring on the inhabitants of our frontiers, the merciless Indian Savages....*

Comment: Do you consider Portuguese to be "a Latin dialect"?

Comment: @tchrist The quote says "late 17th-Century." I don't know where you're getting "before the 17th century." I consider Portugese to be a language with many dialects, all of which are heavily rooted in Latin. Hard consonants are consonant sounds that interrupt the flow of air when you pronounce them, like p-, k-, and d-. You might be more used to the term "stops." I was hoping to find a less technical, more accessible term.

Comment: "Ubiquitous" might've been a poor choice but you can't just substitute one of many synonyms for a word and say that the word is used incorrectly because it's not perfectly interchangeable with the synonym. "Everywhere" is almost always used as hyperbole. Nothing is literally everywhere unless you're talking about some type of ethereal substance (like love or the wisdom of the universe). I would say some things are "more everywhere" than others. Hot dog stands are everywhere in New York City. Cars are more everywhere.

Comment: I'm thinking something unique is getting lost with the watering down of these Latinate u- words. If *ubiquitous* is now to mean nothing more than commonplace rather than in all possible places, what word replaces it? Similarly for all those others.

Comment: Regarding the "Alphabet Song", as children in Australia we learnt this as a simple recital of the letters, with the song ending "Y and Zed", so there was no "me" for Zed to rhyme with. It was only with the introduction of the US show *Sesame Street* in 1971 that the additional words to the song were introduced to Australian audiences. How much earlier were US children singing the song with the additional  verses? My guess is that the change to pronunciation came first, and the rhyming song lyric came very much later.

Comment: PS why not [edit] your post to replace *ubiquitous* with *standard*, and *unanimous* with *common*? The incorrect use of absolute adjectives is likely to prove a significant distraction, given that this EL&U site explicitly caters to **serious English language enthusiasts**. :-)

Comment: It seems the Alphabet Song dates back to around 1835: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_song#The_A.B.C._(Verse_1)). But the entry gives no information on the pronunciation of *Z*.

Comment: @Chappo The bit about the alphabet song popularizing the zee pronunciation is from the Canadian Encyclopedia link. There is a section called “Zee vs. Zed” on the alphabet song Wikipedia page but it basically amounts to “different countries have different variations.” 

While it doesn’t say whether or not the original version had the zee pronunciation, it sounds like it quickly become the standard here due to the rhyme scheme. (I suppose documenting trends in the pronunciation of letters wasn’t considered to be a high priority pursuit).

Comment: As far as the timing goes, the Thomas Lye book was published in 1673 (in England). I imagine for it to be worth including in a spelling book, the pronunciation must have already been quite common, maybe among a younger generation. Bad jokes aside, this strikes as the sort of thing that would start with children despite scolding from their parents.

Comment: You might also want to look into *izzard* and *uzzard.* I think there might be a parallel to look at in the lack of Greek naming for Y, which retains the "Greek I" name or "upsilon" in various languages Euorpean.

Answer (score 4):

Like most things in English at the time of the split between the United States and Great Britain, there was little formalization in the language. Unlike other languages, [there is no English language academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_regulators) to stabilize and standardize pronunciations, spellings, grammar, definitions, etc. And in the 17th and 18th Centuries, there were multiple *names* given to Z in English: zed, zee, [izzard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316665/letter-z-pronounced-as-izzard-how-widespread-and-where), and [uzzard](https://www.wordnik.com/words/uzzard). All of these forms traveled to the Americas in various dialectics. It is likely that many people from regions of Britain that used *Zee* came to the United States (though few records exist for this spoken phenomenon) and this became a popularized way of saying the letter, reinforced by its parallelism with *Bee, Cee, Dee, Gee, Pee, Tee, and Vee.*

[There are numerous other examples of words being retained in American English from older English that have been lost in modern British English.](https://outofthiscentury.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/the-survival-of-archaic-english-in-the-american-dialect/) I don't think the *Zee* example needs any particular special explanation. More important is to realize that other English speaking nations tended to be colonized later and under more direct British influence for longer, thus favoring the "official" British pronunciation of *Zed* (making this one of the easiest ways to identify the difference between a Canadian and an American besides the pronunciation of *about*).

If you just think it is odd that so many European languages retain a more direct link to the Greek *zeta,* you can also marvel over how little *Wye* has to do with either *upsilon* or the Latin *I Graeca.*

Comment: +1 for *Like most things in English at the time of the split between the United States and Great Britain, there was little formalization in the language.* Truer words were never spoken. One has only to compare the late-16th century Geneva Bible with the Authorized Version of 1611 to see some major developments in spelling that happened in a very short time.

Comment: Good commentary. I definitely went into this from the perspective that American English is a mutation of some idealized form. Perhaps it is more helpful to think of the two as isolated subspecies simultaneously adapting to different environments.

Comment: @AffableAmbler It's divergent evolution, where each branch tended to retain some aspects of the older tongue that were lost in the other, and each came up with new innovations that may or may not be adopted in the other. Most British accents were rhotic at the time of the colonizing of America and that's something that was lost pretty recently in (most) British English accents but preserved in (most) of North America.