# Why did Americans make "Z" sound just like "C" when it was already "zed" in British English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I've always been annoyed by how Americans say "Z". They say "zee", which to me sounds identical to "C", "cee". It's a *very* subtle difference if at all.

"Colour" turned into "color" makes sense, but why blur the distinction between "Z" and "C" like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the correct way to refer to the letter "Z" — "Zee" or "Zed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6470/which-is-the-correct-way-to-refer-to-the-letter-z-zee-or-zed) /// (also read [this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z) and [this on Mental Floss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/62639/why-it-zed-britain-and-zee-america))

Comment: The other question does not explain **why** Americans use *zee* instead of *zed,* and would probably have been better asked on IPS (had the site existed at the time).

Comment: Here in Australia we also say "zed", but I've never had any trouble distinguishing between the American "zee" and "cee" when conversing with Americans or watching American TV and movies. I don't think the difference is anywhere near as subtle as you do.

Comment: There is the normal difference of vocalizing the consonant in Zee, and not vocalizing the consonant in See. One needs to develop an ear for it. Zip vs Sip, for example.